# TComponent Design time popup menu access

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How can I add items to my custom component popup menu (right click), like for example version number?

[image]
<sub>(source: [home.pl](http://yota.home.pl/test.JPG))</sub>

Comment: Do you want add a new menu entry or a new property in your component to show the version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this series about component development:

http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc092501b.htm

Comment: Components Editors that what I was looking for, thank You! Where can I find TComponentEditor class in Delphi 2010?

Comment: Thanks, those links are very helpful!